# can this variable really be "referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-admin

I have a piece of code below (belongs to a Django admin view, slightly modified). My IDE (PyCharm) warns me at the last line that `Local variable 'ModelForm' might be referenced before assignment`.

I don't see how that can ever happen, but when I comment out line 6:

```
with transaction.commit_manually():
```

then the warning disappears.

Am I missing something, or is PyCharm missing something?

Here is the chunk of code. I striped it down to just a few lines and it still gives the warning. The original chunk of code is here (70 lines): http://pastebin.com/4UT9hRPb

```
    ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj, form=form)

    formsets = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # commit only when all forms are valid
        with transaction.commit_manually():
            try:
                objects = queryset.all()
                transaction.commit()
                return self.response_change(request, new_object)

            finally:
                general_error = unicode(sys.exc_info()[1])
                transaction.rollback()

    form = ModelForm()
```

Comment: And ``transaction`` is being imported as just that?

Comment: Where does PyCharm complain? At the end of the code or also when you do `form = ModelForm(...)`? Anyway I think it's a bug in PyCharm.

Comment: @Lattyware transaction is imported with `from django.db import transaction`. There is, of course, much more code there originally that makes the use of transaction justified...

Comment: @Bakuriu at the `form = ModelForm()` right there

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in Pycharm myself. Can you give the file to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this warning should not happen, at least I can't see why, maybe PyCharm has a problem figuring out the scope of the `with` block. But you may silence this warning by moving the `ModelForm` assignment in the `with` block.